# My character only moves back-right

Tags: pc, keyboard, dayz-2012, grand-theft-auto-san-andreas

Ever since I accidentally deleted Windows (program files) and restored to an earlier date, I have been having an annoying problem which is happening when I play GTA: San Andreas (and when I'm driving a car in DayZ). It's as if I am holding <kbd>S</kbd> and <kbd>D</kbd> which is making my character always move backwards and right (back-right). I have about 30 games and only those two games are affected by this that I am aware of (I have games such as CS:GO, TF2, Spelunky, BF3 and etc). I don't think its my keyboard (Corsair K70 RGB mechanical keyboard) because I have tried unplugging it and the same problem continues. Please help me fix this problem!

Comment: Have you tried looking through CUE to see if that has something to do with it? Or maybe re-install CUE?

Comment: Unplug any controllers if plugged in.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's affecting only specific games, it's theoretically not your keyboard (which is good news for your wallet). It is a rare instance, but there could be something wrong with your driver. To repair the driver take the following steps, dependent on your version of Windows:

**Windows 7:**

1. Click the start button (usually lower left corner)
2. Click Computer
3. Click Manage
4. Click Device Manager

**Windows 8:**

1. Open the charms menu on the right-hand edge of your screen
2. Click the search option
3. Type in Device Manager
4. Select Device Manager

**Windows 10:**
 1. Press The Windows key and X (Win-X)
 2. Select Device Manager

Then, follow the same cross-version steps from there:

1. Expand they Keyboards menu
2. Right click Standard PS/2 Keyboard (or whatever keyboard is there)
3. Click uninstall
4. Restart your computer **with your keyboard plugged in**
5. Your computer should recognize the keyboard and reinstall the driver correctly

If these steps don't fix your bug, you should first try another keyboard (and if it works you just need a keyboard). If the bug still persists, it's not your keyboard, it's the games. From there you may have to try to reinstall the problematic games (if you can). Otherwise, all you can do is submit a bug report to the game's software company.

Hope that helps!